# why does react native display a scene above a navigator navbar component?

Tags: react-native

Consider this screenshot,

[image]
The white area on top represents a generic `<View>` component while the green/blue combination represents an app specific `<NavBar>` component mounted to the `<Navigation>` obj by setting the prop `navigationBar=`

main code from index.ios.js

```
var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Navigator,
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContent:{
        flex:1
    },
});

class BioStream extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator navigationBar={<NavBar />} renderScene={ (route, nav) => <View style={styles.mainContent}><Text>'some text'</Text></View>  } />
        );
    }
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('BioStream', () => BioStream);
```

and main code from the `NavBar` component definition file,

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer:{
        flex:1
    },

    toolbar:{
        backgroundColor:'#81c04d',
        paddingTop:20,
        paddingBottom:10,
        flexDirection:'row',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1
    },

    toolbarButton:{
        width: 50,
        color:'#fff',
        textAlign:'center'
    },

    toolbarTitle:{
        color:'#fff',
        textAlign:'center',
        fontWeight:'bold',
        flex:1
    },

    content:{
        backgroundColor:'blue',
        flex:1                //Step 2
    }
});

class NavBar extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
         <View style={styles.mainContainer} >
            <View style={styles.toolbar}>
                <Text style={styles.toolbarButton}>Add</Text>
                <Text style={styles.toolbarTitle}>This is the title</Text>
                <Text style={styles.toolbarButton}>Like</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.content}>
            </View>
         </View>
        )
    }
};

module.exports = NavBar;
```

What am I failing to understand about how this layout (and/or the general nature of react native layouts) should be constructed?  It is my intent to place the navbar consistently in all scenes at the top of the frame and have all scene content/code get rendered below.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems because react native  component render navigation bar after scene [(source code here)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/Navigator.js#L1117-L1130).You can set styles to your custom navigation bar to get it act well.

There's no issue related with this,you can open one on [react native project](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues) to get the reason why it should be like this.

Answer (score 0):

It is now handled by react native i guess (focus on style={styles.navigator}):

```
<Navigator
      style={styles.navigator}
      navigationBar={
        <NavBar />
      }

      configureScene={this._configureScene}
      initialRoute={this.state}
      ref="featuresNavigator"
      renderScene= {this._renderScene}

/>
```

And the style :

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
      navigator: {
            flexDirection: 'column-reverse'
      },
});
```

More :
if the navbar don't appear, you have to set an height in its style  `<NavBar style={{height: 40}}/>`